# Add background color to individual listview elements

Tags: java, android, listview

I am currently designing an app in which the user clicks on a button, and the text from that button is added to the listview. Here are condensed versions of `activity_main.xml` and `MainActivity.java`

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/good"
            android:text="Good"
            android:background="#99CC00"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/bad"
            android:text="Bad"
            android:background="#FFBB33"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/ugly"
            android:text="Ugly"
            android:background="#9933CC"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        Button good = (Button) findViewById(R.id.good);
        Button bad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bad);
        Button ugly = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ugly);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist);

        good.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mylist.add("Good");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);        
            }
        });

        bad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mylist.add("Bad");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);        
            }
        });

        ugly.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mylist.add("Good");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);        
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This design works great, but I'm trying to add one more thing: when a particular button is clicked and that particular word is added as an element in the `listview`, I would like to make that element have the same background color as the button. For example, if the user clicks the button `Good`, I would like the text `Good` that appears in the `listview` to have the background color `#99CC00`. Similarly, for `Bad`, I would like the background color to be `#FFBB33`, and `#9933CC` for `Ugly`. Does anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: Use an Adapter for elements that contain string and color information and extend ArrayAdapter overriding `getView`. To produce `View`s with the desired color / set the color of the existing view.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a custom adapter for the ListView. This gives you complete control over each view in the list. It's actually not that hard to do: [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

The magic happens in getView() and that's where you'll have to check the string value of the item and apply the background color according to which word it is.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality:

```
1).you have to make a custom adapter and set it into your listview.
2).in getview method of your custom adapter just get the id of your custom inflator layout.
3). now according to positions you can set the background of your individual items in the listview.
```

Below is the code sample that fullfil your requirement.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _scontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_product_display_inflator, parent, false);

        LinearLayout f_l = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pr_bg);
        if (position % 3 == 0) {
            f_l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.campaignbase_black);
        } else if (position % 3 == 1) {
            f_l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.campaignbase_pink);
        } else if (position % 3 == 2) {
            f_l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.campaignbase_brown);
        }
          return itemView;
    }
```

_scontext is the context of your adapter class.